# Links inside Bootstrap list-group not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code. As you can see is a list-group of anchors that redirect to different sections (here changed to Twitter address in order to test the code) and a final dropdown menu with internal links too. You can [check it in bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rmhLUMvGhS) too. And as you can see, the links are not working. Even if I take out the dropdown menu, it still doesn't work. It does nothing, and I am clueless about why.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  .list-group.panel > .list-group-item {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
  }
  .list-group-submenu {
    margin-left:20px;
  }
</style>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="http://twitter.com" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled" id="10_2016" target="_blank">
    October 2016
    <span class="badge" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-original-title="Active news">0</span>
    <span class="badge badge-gray pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-original-title="Inactive news">0</span>
  </a>
  <a href="http://twitter.com" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="9_2016" target="_blank">
    September 2016
    <span class="badge" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-original-title="Active news">2</span>
    <span class="badge badge-gray pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-original-title="Inactive news">0</span>
  </a>
  <!-- Here go more months -->
  <a aria-expanded="true" href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">
    Historic <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <span class="badge">1</span>
  </a>
  <div aria-expanded="true" style="" class="list-group-submenu collapse in" id="SubMenu1">
    <a href="http://twitter.com" class="list-group-item active" data-parent="#SubMenu1" target="_blank">
      2015
      <span class="badge">1</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Here go more years -->
  </div>
</div>
```

As @MoshFeu and @almostabeginner have proved in the comments, the code works, but it doesn't work in my project. Here I add a few more details about the environment of this code and what I've tried:
The project is PHP, the html is prepared in a function in a class and echoed inside a column and row in bootstrap. I have changed the internal URL in href by the twitter URL to be sure the path was not bad. I have very little js going on on that page. In the console I can't see any malformed html or js errors. There is some specific styles for that page, but the only styles about links are about their colour. So I don't know what else could I try.

Comment: It works for me: http://output.jsbin.com/yuqozuxedo

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you have set `target="_blank"`, remove that line and it should work.

http://www.bootply.com/VX0dtnLSbF

Clearly bootply does not allow new window, I tried

```
onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;"
```

in bootply, and it still did not work, but the link works.

If you ever want to debug JS I suggest using Chrome "inspect" feature, that will make your life easy.

Edit to add:

This is the message you get when you click the Twitter link:

> Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/' in a frame because an
>   ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Simply put, bootply does not allow it, otherwise the link is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't know where he is testing his code, but in bootply example he gave, the target="_blank" was the issue. and yes, you are right, it should work even with target="_blank"

Comment: Yes because all those tools runs the output in an iframe.

Comment: First, I am a she. 
Second, it doesn't work in my app and the `target="_blank` is not the problem there, I added it only to the question. In your bootply I just see a blank page. Is that how bootply manages external links? It's the first time I use it. I see it works in @MoshFeu jsbin, but still I don't know what's wrong with it...

Comment: @Ika Sorry for the gender assumption.. when you run the code in the bootply link I provided, right click on the blank screen, and select inspect. You will see what I mean.

Comment: @Ika is your project is public (Can you provide a link?). Is there any errors in the console during the click?

Comment: @MoshFeu There is not any console error during the click in my project, but sadly it is not public. If there is any more code I can provide or a workaround to this, I'd be glad. Also, other links in the same page work fine, so I don't see how could there be any js blocking links just inside this block.

Comment: Plus, I've tried opening it and checking the console both in Chrome and Firefox to see if the problem was just in one of them, but neither consoles show errors while clicking on the links.

Comment: @Ika I just copied your code (without any edits), pasted it in notepad, saveas home.html, opened it in Chrome, clicked September 2016 and it opened Twitter in a new tab. It clearly works. The problem is with your environment, unless you provide more detail, we can only make wild assumptions.

Comment: @almostabeginner I can see that, I mean, you and MoshFeu have proved it beyond reasonable doubt in your answers and comments, but I have no idea where to start looking. If you have any wild assumption about where should I investigate further, it is more than welcome. I will add more info in the question.

Comment: @Ika we can't help without see the actual problem. It can be anything. If you can upload your project (at least the part which cause the problem) so we can see it. If you can't there is nothing we can help with. Sorry.

Comment: I answered my own question a moment ago, it was a preventdefault in a js function. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It was a stupid e.preventdefault in a stupid included file. Sorry I made you lose your time with this!